# GeoServer raster tiles are individually contrast-balanced: how to turn this off?

Tags: raster, geoserver, tiling

I'm running GeoServer locally as a servlet (in JBoss), and I'm serving a GeoTIFF file through the WMS protocol.  In a webpage running an OpenLayers map, I have the GeoTIFF-WMS layer overlaid above an OpenStreetMaps base layer.  The problem is that it looks like this:

[image: GeoTIFF over OpenStreetMap]

The GeoTIFF is clearly being tiled (good) and each tile is normalized to a given brightness level (bad).  When I zoom in, I can see a similar effect taking place on the smaller tiles, and I know that the original GeoTIFF doesn't have this blockiness: it's a diagonal strip of 16-bit greyscale surrounded by zeros that ought to be transparent.

How do I turn off this brightness-normalization feature (or what is it called, so that I can Google it)?

Even better, how do I tell GeoServer that pixels with zero values ought to be transparent?

Comment: How have you loaded the geotiff? is it one file or several? one layer or a mosaic?

Comment: I pointed GeoServer to the GeoTIFF file and GeoServer did its magic (some of which I want to undo).  It's one file, one layer, one band (greyscale, 16-bits).

Comment: thats odd - it looks like three separate images. what happens if you turn tiling off

Comment: I turned off "Create a cached layer for this layer" in "Tile Caching", but this only turned off the caching.  I can't find an option to turn off tiling completely.  (What would that mean, anyway?  Serve the whole 7 MB image each time the map is viewed?)

Comment: It looks like your client (openlayers?) is requesting tiles instead of a whole image - remove that option and see what happens

Comment: In the `OpenLayers.Layer.WMS` constructor arguments, I added `tiled: false` (which is how the JS from GeoServer's Layer Preview selects tiled/untiled views), but the image looks the same as shown above.  It's clearly making tiles, so I don't know what's wrong with that parameter setting.

*However,* I do want to make tiles; the issue is that it's brightness-balancing each tile individually.  What would you call this brightness-balancing feature?  I haven't been able to find references to it by searching the web because I don't know its name.

Comment: Is it not possible to turn off the contrast adjustment to have a uniform level across tiles? This is effect prevents us from tiling and caching the requests for coverages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a poor solution: use a WorldImage instead.  I converted my GeoTIFF to PNG and created an associated `.pngw` file, then loaded it as a WorldImage store.  It still seems to be tiling (good), but it presents the intensity as-is, without balancing it (also good).

This works for me because I'll be generating my output programmatically, and PNG is an easier format to write to than GeoTIFF.